# Creating a wine static executable?

Tags: windows, linux, wine

I have some windows command line applications, in binary form (I do not have the source code) which I use frequently. Sometimes I need to run them in Linux machines, and it works perfectly under wine (wine is not an emulator). The problem I'm facing now is that I need to work on a cluster which has not wine installed on it. I wonder if it is possible to create in another similar linux machine kind of a static executable or so, so i can run this windows program on the cluster

Thanks

Comment: sorry, I forgot to say that I can not install anything on that cluster

Answer (score 0):

This is an insane idea ;) Install wine on that cluster. What stops you? If you can execute programs there....

If this is some kind of serious software, it don't recommend to run it on non-native OS. Wine is not developed for running critical applications. It is still not Windows.

Comment: I just will try to install wine from source code

this is kind of a old fortran 77 code application which runs fine under wine

Comment: Don't install wine from sources. Install from rpm or deb. It is much easier. If this is a simple app, then why to run it on a cluster? BTW, what do you mean under "cluster"? I thought, cluster is a several PCs, working together on some task.

Comment: There are perfectly reasonable conditions under which users don't get root access, and can't install software.  Clearly large academic or commercial clusters are one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compile a static exe; Windows is too complex for that. But you might be able to compile Wine to run on your cluster.

What you need is a way to compile code on the cluster. Wine itself can be installed anywhere but since I don't know if you have all the dependencies on the cluster, it might take some work.

So I suggest to get the Wine sources, run `configure --prefix=$HOME/wine && make` and then work through the errors.

(`--prefix` is the path under which Wine will be installed; it should be some path that is the same on the cluster and your build host. If all else fails, `ln` is your friend).

Answer (score 0):

I've just spent a couple minutes looking for a reference to the knowledge in my head but it my googling isn't up to it.

Picasa for linux is bundled with Wine, so it may be possible but I couldn't find the article I read a couple months back.

Other than this, you can cross compile with gcc and winelib but as Cyper rightly said, no code no compilation.